# how to generate event on dynamically generated anchor tag

Tags: html, jsp, jquery

im trying to generate an event on anchor tag which itself is inside dynamically generated row of table by jquery. but iam unable to do so. please let me know it is not working and way accomplish.
here is my html  and jquery code.

```
HTML
<a href="#" id="1"  class="genrow" ><img src="images/add.png"  border="0" /></a>

JQuery Code
$(".genrow").click(function (){
var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td>1</td>
<td"><a href="#" class="genevent" ><img src="add.png"/></a></td></tr>');
});

$(".genevent").click(function (){    
 alert("Generate event");
});
```

Why click function on .genevent is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Since the anchor tag is added dynamically, you need to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('click', '.genevent', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Generate event"); 
});
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtRGB/)

Answer (score 0):

use `on` event delegation. and delegate it to closest static parent

```
 $(document).on('click',".genevent",function (){    
     alert("Generate event");
 });
```

Comment: Thnks for rply but it doesn't work for me. it gives javascript error: $(...).on is not a function

Comment: whatis the error that you are getting... can u post it here ??

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on dynamically generated elements .

As dynamically generated elements are not part of DOM at DOM ready o Page load you can not bind the events directly so you have to use `Event Delegation`.

```
$(document).on('click',".genevent",function (){    
     alert("Generate event");
});
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Comment: exactly as mine..  :)

Comment: @bipen yeah but it's the correct answer n we wrote in near about same time .